# Count amount of unique words from a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 40 000 ish text file.
All the words from the text file are saved in an ArrayList.

I want to find how many unique words there are in that file and return that value to the main class.
So if there is a unique word the counter goes up by one.

I would like the output to be

```
   Amount of unique words: 7000
```

I tried

```
       public int antallOrd() {
          Set<Ord> unik = new HashSet<Ord>(ordListe) ;
            for (Ord unikt : unik) {
            System.out.println(nokkel + ": " + Collections.frequency(ordListe, nokkel));
       }
```

but didnt quite understand how to implement a counter to this

thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to, `Set` guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to iterate through `unik` - it is a set, and putting all the words in that set removed the duplicates.  The size of `unik` is the answer to your question.

Comment: Do you mean like this: 

  `  Set<Ord> unik = new HashSet<Ord>(ordListe) ;
      return unik.size() ;`

because when I dont get amount of unique words, just the same amount of words as in the original arraylist

Comment: I had missed the fact that you aren't making a set of the words; I don't know what relationship an Ord object has with a word, and can only assume that an ordListe is a list of Ords. If you make a set of words, that will be your unique count. (This is why many people on this site insist on a runnable example, so we don't have to fill in gaps with assumptions.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the words into a java.util.Bag and print the size() of the bag.

You could also use Hashtable keyed on the word if you wanted to keep a count of each word.